# How to select all columns, and a count(*) in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle

In often use in TSQL the following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), * 
FROM CUSTOMER c 
WHERE c.Name like 'foo%';
```

When I try to execute this query in Oracle SQL Developer it doesn't work and throws me an error:

> "Missing expression"

What is the good syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will have to use group by.. or combine the result of two queries.

Comment: Plz provide schema of your Table..

Comment: I don't believe that statement works in SQL Server

Comment: You should be able to use `COUNT(*) OVER ()` or similar.

Comment: Shahid Iqbal, could you explain the group by method please ? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach is to do something like the following.  This will result in a count(*) result for each line.  But beware, there is a Cartesianjoin; if you have many rows like 'foo%' this will perform badly.

```
select a.cntr, c.*
from CUSTOMER c 
   , (select count(*) cntr
     from customer b
     where b.name like 'foo%' ) a
where c.name like 'foo%'
```

Answer (score 75):

This will perform better:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (), c.*
FROM CUSTOMER c 
WHERE c.Name like 'foo%';
```

Comment: explanation would have been nice

Comment: @Blauhim, it's an analytic function with an empty window clause - so it calculates the count of rows over the entire result set. It will usually perform better because it should only visit each block of the table once, counting the rows as it goes.

Comment: @Jeffrey This is nice, but the extra columns for every row it creates tends to cause more overhead than a select count(*), especially if you have an aggregate for every column. Is it possible to have this same aggregate as the first row only and does not repeat again for each row?

Comment: @user3758745, that won't save anything. The "overhead" of adding one extra numeric column to the result set is negligible compared to the savings you make because you didn't read all the data from the table a second time. The requirement *as stated in this question* was to add the count to the same result set as an additional column, anyway.

Comment: @Jeffrey this question already had a chosen answer so I thought of asking a seperate question. I have a problem where I have to do 2 queries: select * and select aggregate. I thought this would reduce the runtime by at least 30% but it actually adds a few more seconds to compare to the select union queries on table without index. I imagine it would be worse on table with index as the 2 times table scan gets reduced even more. Oh, and you said "this will perform better" on your answer so my question is valid!

Comment: It would be more accurate to say "*all else being equal* this will perform better". If there are any usable indexes things get more complicated - if there's a suitable index a count(*) on that will usually perform much better than doing a count from a full table scan.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thanks! my username is Blauhi**r**n, so your @ tag did not catch me ^.^

Comment: You should add the explanation to the answer itself

Comment: I think @user3758745 has a very good warning.  I ran some small tests and found that this is much slower (~4x) than doing a subquery.  Obviously YMMV based on your result set like Jeffrey Kemp said.

Answer (score 1):

here below MySQL code is the way to get both select * from and total rows returned in a single query.

```
$result = $db->get_results("SELECT a.total, c.* FROM tableName c, 
(select count(*) total from tableName b where b.post=25) a 
where c.post=25");
```

then you can get variable total to get count, and * can use for based on your table column.

But how to get the total without foreach() or directly into a vaiable?

I go it total without foreach Here:

```
echo "Total: ".count($result);
```