# How to add count with active record association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Requirement is to send the count size of the database with active record association

I am trying to limit the size of record and want to load more options and clicking on load more will give all records

```
records = company.public_send(table).joins(:customer).where(customer_id: ids).order(sorting)
#records = records.count(:id) #300
records = records.limit(5)
```

This return me active record, along with this i want to send entire size of record 
How can i do it

Comment: Are you looking for pagination?

Comment: no i just want to know the total size of records in data base , along with the limited record @sureshprasanna70

Comment: wouldn't `company.customers.count` give you the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with straight solution by using 2 queries:

- One for select
- One for total count

This is the simplest solution compare to others and it's easy to understand.

Second, I think any pagination will do, but if since you don't use all the features, not worth it.

Not limited to that, you can still do one query, but the count will be linked to each record and the performance is nothing better.

```
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17206119/1600046
records = company.public_send(table).joins(:customer).where(customer_id: ids).order(sorting)
records = records.select("table_name.*, COUNT(*) OVER () as total").limit(1)
records.first.try(:total) # in case empty record
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it with one query is to use `except`, which in my opinion is not the cleanest way but does what you need.

So, in your case `total_count = records.limit(5).except(:limit).count`