# How to add multiple requests into a SELECT statement SQL

Tags: sql, select

How can I request all columns (*) in a table while at the same time counting all distinct items in a id_number column?
(Learning SQL Thanks for your help)

Comment: This sounds like it should be two separate queries. Also, as a best practice, you should generally only use SELECT * as a placeholder while still in the building process for complex queries, and always list out the column names in the final version of a query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all columns, and a count(\*) in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187124/how-to-select-all-columns-and-a-count-in-the-same-query)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WITH` to make a sub-query like:

```
WITH with_tbl_a AS 
     (SELECT * FROM tbl_a) 
     SELECT a.col_1, count(b.pk), etc...
       FROM with_tbl_a
       INNER JOIN tbl_b b ON a.fk = b.pk
```

Hope that it helps you.